# Why doesn't sympy support units with 0 magnitude?

Tags: python, sympy, units-of-measurement

The title says it all... why does sympy have the following behavior?

```
import sympy.physics.units as u
print(0*u.meter)
# >>> 0
```

And Pint has this behavior:

```
import pint
u = pint.UnitRegistry()
print(0*u.meter)
# >>> 0 meter
```

I think I prefer pint's behavior, because it allows for dimensional consistency. 0 is a proper magnitude of some unit. For instance, 0 degrees kelvin has a definitive meaning... it's not just the absence of anything...

So I realize the contributors of sympy probably chose this implementation for some reason. Can you help me see the light?

Comment: SymPy does not even distinguish real zero from complex zero. Neither does Wolfram Mathematica. I believe that zero is zero. You can set the scale factor of a quantity to be zero, as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion of reasons for implementation belongs on GitHub (where I [raised this issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14374)), not here. A short answer is that units are a bolted-on structure; the core of SymPy is not really unit-aware.

You can create `0*meter` expression by passing evaluate=False parameter to Mul:

```
>>> Mul(0, u.meter, evaluate=False)
0*meter
```

However, it will become 0 if combined with something else.

```
>>> 3*Mul(0, u.meter, evaluate=False)
0
```

Wrapping in UnevaluatedExpr prevents the above, but causes more problems than it solves.

```
>>> 3*UnevaluatedExpr(Mul(0, u.meter, evaluate=False))
3*(0*meter)
```

Comment: Thanks for linking to the issue and sorry I didn't see it earlier!